Error: Timeout of 900000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves
I'm encountering a timeout error while running a unit test for my Lottery smart contract using Hardhat. The error occurs during the test case that involves picking a winner, resetting the lottery, and sending money. Below is the relevant portion of my test code:
it("picks a winner, resets the lottery, and sends money", async () => {
              const additionalEntrants = 3
              const startingAccountIndex = 1 //deployer = 0
              const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
              for (
                  let i = startingAccountIndex;
                  i < startingAccountIndex + additionalEntrants;
                  i++
              ) {
                  const accountConnectedLottery = lottery.connect(accounts[i])
                  await accountConnectedLottery.enterLottery({ value: lotteryEnteranceFee })
              }
              const startingTimeStamp = await lottery.getLatestTimeStamp()

              //   performUpKeep (mock being Chainlink Keepers)
              //   fulfillRandomWords (mock being the Chainlink VRF)
              //   we will have to wait for the fulfillRandomWords to be called
              await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                  lottery.once("WinnerPicked", async () => {
                      console.log("Found the event!")
                      try {
                          const recentWinner = await lottery.getRecentWinner()
                          console.log(recentWinner)
                          console.log(accounts[2].address)
                          console.log(accounts[0].address)
                          console.log(accounts[1].address)
                          console.log(accounts[3].address)
                          const lotteryState = await lottery.getLotteryState()
                          const endingTimeStamp = await lottery.getLatestTimeStamp()
                          const numPlayers = await lottery.getNumberOfPlayers()
                          const winnerEndingBalnce = await accounts[1].getBalance()
                          assert.equal(numPlayers.toString, "0")
                          assert.equal(lotteryState.toString, "0")
                          assert(endingTimeStamp > startingTimeStamp)
                          assert.equal(
                              winnerEndingBalnce.toString(),
                              winnerStartingBalance.add(
                                  lotteryEnteranceFee
                                      .mul(additionalEntrants)
                                      .add(lotteryEnteranceFee)
                                      .toString(),
                              ),
                          )
                          resolve()
                      } catch (e) {
                          reject(e)
                      }
                  })
                  //Setting up the listener
                  const tx = await lottery.performUpKeep([])
                  const txReceipt = await tx.wait(1)

                  //   // Ensure txReceipt.events[1].args.requestId is correct
                  //   const requestId = txReceipt.events[1].args.requestId
                  //   console.log("Request ID:", requestId)

                  //   below, we will fire the event and the listener will pick it up and resolve
                  const winnerStartingBalance = await accounts[1].getBalance()
                  await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(
                      txReceipt.events[1].args.requestId,
                      lottery.address,
                  )
              })
          })
      

Solidity code:
//SPDX-License-Modifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

// Enter the lottery (paying some amount)
// Pick a random winner (varifiably randome)
// Winner to be selected every X minutes --> completely automated

// Chainlink oracle is necessary for randomness and automated execution(Chainlink keeper)
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/automation/interfaces/AutomationCompatibleInterface.sol";

error Lottery__NotEnoughETHEntered();
error Lottery_TransferFailed();
error Lottery_NotOpen();
error Lottery_UpKeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 lotteryState);



contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBaseV2, AutomationCompatibleInterface {
    /* Type declaration*/
    enum LotteryState {
        OPEN,
        CALCULATING
    } //uint256 0=OPEN, 1=CALCULATING

    /* State Variables */
    uint256 private immutable i_enteranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    //Lottery Variables
    address private s_recentWinner;
    LotteryState private s_lotteryState;
    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;

    /* Evnets*/
    event LotteryEnter(address indexed player);
    event RequestedLotteryWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed winner);

    /* Functions */
    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2, //contract address
        uint256 enteranceFee,
        bytes32 gasLane,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit,
        uint256 interval
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_enteranceFee = enteranceFee;
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        s_lotteryState = LotteryState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp; //block.timestamp is a globally known variable
        i_interval = interval;
    }

    function enterLottery() public payable {
        if (msg.value < i_enteranceFee) {
            revert Lottery__NotEnoughETHEntered();
        }
        if (s_lotteryState != LotteryState.OPEN) {
            revert Lottery_NotOpen();
        }
        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));

        emit LotteryEnter(msg.sender);
    }

    /**
     * @dev This is the function that the Chainlink Keeper nodes call
     * they look for the `upKeepNeeded` to return true.
     * The following should be true in order to return true:
     * 1. Our time interval should have passed
     * 2. The lottery should have at least 1 player, and have some ETH
     * 3. Our subscription is funded with LINK
     * 4. The lottery should be in an "open" state.
     */
function checkUpkeep(
    bytes memory /*checkData*/
) public override returns (bool upKeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData*/) {
    bool isOpen = (LotteryState.OPEN == s_lotteryState);
    bool timePassed = (block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval;
    bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
    bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
    upKeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);
}

function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*performData*/) external override {
    (bool upKeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
    if (!upKeepNeeded) {
        revert Lottery_UpKeepNotNeeded(
            address(this).balance,
            s_players.length,
            uint256(s_lotteryState)
        );
    }

    s_lotteryState = LotteryState.CALCULATING;

    uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
        i_gasLane, //gasLane
        i_subscriptionId, //Subscription ID that we need for funding requests (here it is to request a random number)
        REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS, //It says how many confirmations the chainlink node should wait before responding
        i_callbackGasLimit, //The limit for how much gas to use for the callback request to our contract's fulfillRandomWords() function.
        NUM_WORDS // number of random words we need
    );

    //THis is redudant!!
    emit RequestedLotteryWinner(requestId);
}

function fulfillRandomWords(
    uint256 /*requestId*/,
    uint256[] memory randomWords
) internal override {
    uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
    address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
    s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
    s_lotteryState = LotteryState.OPEN;
    s_players = new address payable[](0);
    s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
    (bool success, ) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");

    if (!success) {
        revert Lottery_TransferFailed();
    }
    emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
}

/* view / pure functions*/

function getEnteranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
    return i_enteranceFee;
}

function getPalyers(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
    return s_players[index];
}

function getRecentWinner() public view returns (address) {
    return s_recentWinner;
}

function getLotteryState() public view returns (LotteryState) {
    return s_lotteryState;
}

function getNumWords() public pure returns (uint256) {
    return NUM_WORDS;
}

function getNumberOfPlayers() public view returns (uint256) {
    return s_players.length;
}

function getLatestTimeStamp() public view returns (uint256) {
    return s_lastTimeStamp;
}

function getRequestConfirmations() public pure returns (uint256) {
    return REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS;
}

function getInterval() public view returns (uint256) {
    return i_interval;


 }
}

Error:
1) Lottery Unit Tests
   fulfillRandomWords
     picks a winner, resets the lottery, and sends money:
 Error: Timeout of 200000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (E:\Blockachain  32hrs course\Lottery(Hardhat)\SmartContract\test\unit\Lottery.test.js)
  at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
  at processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)

I've confirmed that the "WinnerPicked" event is not being emitted within the test's timeout period. I suspect the issue might be related to how I'm setting up the listener or triggering the fulfillRandomWords function.
I have identified that there seems to be an issue with my checkUpkeep() function, as it is not being triggered by the automation process. Consequently, the performUpkeep() function is not executing as expected. While I have pinpointed the source of the issue, I am unsure how to proceed in resolving it.

The timeout is due to the fact that it's trying to call the function that doesn't exist as you've spelled performUpkeep wrong  with a capital K (i.e., performUpKeep) in your test, and since that call  is not enclosed within a try-catch, so it remains in the awaiting state without being resolved or rejected.
The revised test would be:
it("picks a winner, resets the lottery, and sends money", async () => {
    const additionalEntrants = 3
    const startingAccountIndex = 1 //deployer = 0
    const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
    for (
        let i = startingAccountIndex;
        i < startingAccountIndex + additionalEntrants;
        i++
    ) {
        const accountConnectedLottery = lottery.connect(accounts[i])
        await accountConnectedLottery.enterLottery({ value: lotteryEnteranceFee })
    }
    const startingTimeStamp = await lottery.getLatestTimeStamp()

    //   performUpKeep (mock being Chainlink Keepers)
    //   fulfillRandomWords (mock being the Chainlink VRF)
    //   we will have to wait for the fulfillRandomWords to be called
    await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("here")
        lottery.once("WinnerPicked", async () => {
            console.log("Found the event!")
            try {
                const recentWinner = await lottery.getRecentWinner()
                console.log(recentWinner)
                console.log(accounts[2].address)
                console.log(accounts[0].address)
                console.log(accounts[1].address)
                console.log(accounts[3].address)
                const lotteryState = await lottery.getLotteryState()
                const endingTimeStamp = await lottery.getLatestTimeStamp()
                const numPlayers = await lottery.getNumberOfPlayers()
                const winnerEndingBalnce = await accounts[1].getBalance()
                assert.equal(numPlayers.toString, "0")
                assert.equal(lotteryState.toString, "0")
                assert(endingTimeStamp > startingTimeStamp)
                assert.equal(
                    winnerEndingBalnce.toString(),
                    winnerStartingBalance.add(
                        lotteryEnteranceFee
                            .mul(additionalEntrants)
                            .add(lotteryEnteranceFee)
                            .toString(),
                    ),
                )
                resolve()
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e)
            }
        })
        //Setting up the listener

        try {

            const tx = await lottery.performUpkeep([])
            const txReceipt = await tx.wait(1)

            //   // Ensure txReceipt.events[1].args.requestId is correct
            //   const requestId = txReceipt.events[1].args.requestId
            //   console.log("Request ID:", requestId)

            //   below, we will fire the event and the listener will pick it up and resolve
            const winnerStartingBalance = await accounts[1].getBalance()
            console.log("here 2")
            await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(
                txReceipt.events[1].args.requestId,
                lottery.address,
            )
            resolve()
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            reject(e);
        }
    })
})

But, now you would face InvalidConsumer() error as you haven't added your Lottery contract as a consumer to the VRFCoordinatorV2Mock contract's subscription, so you need to call addConsumer in your beforeEach, like:
beforeEach(async () => {
    deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
    await deployments.fixture(["all"])
    const vrfCoordinatorV2MockDeployed = await deployments.get("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
    vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt(
        "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock",
        vrfCoordinatorV2MockDeployed.address,
    )
    const lotteryDeployed = await deployments.get("Lottery")
    lottery = await ethers.getContractAt("Lottery", lotteryDeployed.address)
    lotteryEnteranceFee = await lottery.getEnteranceFee()
    interval = await lottery.getInterval()

    // Adding Lottery contract as consumer
    vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(1n, lotteryDeployed.address)
})


Thanks for bringing it up. However, I'm still getting the same error

Please share your code as a GitHub repo, so that I can try on my end.

Thank you. Here is the link to my git repo: https://github.com/Alisha-Reddy/lottery_smartContract/tree/main

I've edited my answer. Please check.

Hi. Can you explain me what's the "1n" in vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(1n, lotteryDeployed.address)?

It's the subscription id that you have created by executing 01-deploy-lottery.js (in this line). Make sure to console log it at the time of executing the deployment script, and note it down somewhere.

Kindly please mark the answer as accepted, if it helped you. Thanks.

Thank you for your help. However, I am still experiencing the same problem. I have identified that there seems to be an issue with my checkUpkeep() function, as it is not being triggered by the automation process. Consequently, the performUpkeep() function is not executing as expected. While I have pinpointed the source of the issue, I am unsure how to proceed in resolving it.

Have you replaced your picks a winner, resets the lottery, and sends money test, with the one that I’d shared in the answer?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
